# How can I list the all the resources attached to a IAM role using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I wish to list down all the resources that is attached to a IAM role. 
I am writing a program that would clean up the IAM roles that are not associated with any resources(like ec2 resource, lambda, task definition etc.)

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iam')
iam = boto3.resource('iam')
roles = client.list_roles()
role_name = []
Role_list = roles['Roles']
for key in Role_list:
    role_name.append(key['RoleName'])
print(*role_name,sep='\n')

for name in role_name:
    role = iam.Role( name )
    print(name)   
    print(role.get_available_subresources())
```

Comment: The IAM.Role resource includes various policy collections: attached_policies, instance_profiles, and policies.

Comment: What do you mean by "resources that is attached to a IAM role"? Are you asking for resources that are _using_ the IAM Role, or are you referring to the permissions that are granted by the IAM Role?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am looking to list the resources that are using the IAM role like EC2, lambda, task definition etc

Answer (score 0):

There is no command to list all resources that are "using" an IAM Role.

Instead, you would need to retrieve a list for each type of resource and then check the IAM Role that is assigned to each of them.

Also, please note that applications can **assume an IAM Role** through an API call in their code. Therefore, they are "using" an IAM Role, but there is no specific assignment of the role to the application.

Answer (score -1):

You can use get_role(RoleName="MyRoleName") to get the attached resources.

[Boto3 Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_role)

```
iam = boto3.client('iam')
role_policy = iam.get_role(RoleName="MyRoleName")
print (role_policy)
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    'Role': {
        'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/Test-Role',
        'AssumeRolePolicyDocument': '<URL-encoded-JSON>',
        'CreateDate': datetime(2013, 4, 18, 5, 1, 58, 3, 108, 0),
        'Path': '/',
        'RoleId': 'AIDIODR4TAW7CSEXAMPLE',
        'RoleName': 'Test-Role',
    },
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```